# Can I use a Corpse Cur to get a Vector Asp back from the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I attack with a [Vector Asp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vector%20Asp) and use his activated ability to give him infect until the end of the turn. It's blocked by a 2/2 creature and goes to the graveyard.

If I cast [Corpse Cur](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Corpse%20Cur) next, can I return Vector Asp to my hand from the graveyard?

On the one hand, the Vector Asp did have infect until the end of the turn. On the other, he may have lost that by going to the graveyard. Which is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer in the comprehensive rules:

> **400.7**. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

So once the Vector Asp goes to my graveyard, it has no memory of the infect I gave it with its activated ability. So, I can't use the Corpse Cur to get it back.

Comment: I realize this is a very old answer, but it's worth noting that the above answer includes something very important that this one does not. There is a very important distinction between a "creature" and a "creature card." A "creature" is a permanent on the battlefield; that is what had infect. Corpse Cur can only target a "creature card with infect", and the Vector Asp card doesn't have infect, whether or not it could represent a creature that does.

Answer (score 21):

Corpse Cur says "return target creature card with infect." Although Vector Asp had infect when it went to the graveyard, the creature *card* Vector Asp in the 'yard doesn't have it. Not a valid target.